# NAO Robot (Choregraphe) ALProxy Error

Tags: proxy, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

When I am using Choregraphe for NAO Robot's 3D/Computer-Generated view (the simulation) I get an error with the Record Video and Speech Recognition functions.

The errors are:

```
[ERROR] behavior.box :onLoad:22 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11803614104__root__RecordVideo_3__RecordVideo_4:     ALProxy::ALProxy
    Can't find service: ALVideoRecorder
```

and

```
[ERROR] behavior.box :__init__:10 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_11803614104__root__SpeechReco_16:  ALProxy::ALProxy
    Can't find service: ALSpeechRecognition
```

Picture of Choregraphe View

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because when you are using the "virtual Nao" you cannot access to the camera or the speech recognition functions (no microphone or camera available)